# Determine the volume of the area

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I have solved the following problem and wonder if my thoughts were correct:

**Find the volume of the field of all points $(x,y,z)$, that simultaniously lie under the cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and above the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$.**

Here's how I proceed:

The volume of the restricted area is nothing else than $$\int_{\Omega}d\mu$$ with $\Omega:=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3\lvert\;x^2+y^2\leq z\leq\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\}$. In order to make the calculations easier we transform to cylindrical coordinates. The order of the integration can be any according to the Fubini's law.

$$x^2+y^2=r^2,\;\Omega=\{(r,\phi,z)\in[0,\infty[\;\times\;[0,2\pi]\;\times\;\mathbb R\lvert\;0\leq r\leq1, \; r^2\leq z\leq r\}\\
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^1dr\int_{r^2}^rdz=\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^1dr\;z\Big|_{r^2}^r \\
=\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^1\;r-r^2dr\\
=\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\frac12r^2-\frac13r^3\Bigg|_0^1\\
=\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\frac16=\frac16\phi\Bigg|_0^{2\pi}\\
={\pi \over 3}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Is it correct or am I somewhere mistaking?

Comment: The measure should read $rdrd\phi dz$.

Comment: @Frédéric that's true, I see, you are right

Comment: Where r is the Jacobian.

Answer (score 1):

Using the correct volume measure $dV=rdrd\phi dz$ as pointed out by Frédéric, we obtain:

$$\left(\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\right)\int_0^1 rdr\int_{r^2}^rdz=2\pi\int_0^1 (r-r^2)rdr=\frac{\pi}{6}$$